# Loading only jsp tab contents on tab click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, tabs, multiview

I have a JSP page with four tabs and a background image. I want that when I click one of the tab, a JSP function should be invoked that will only update the clicked tab contents not the whole page and background image. A similar example can be the Multiview control in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is not comparable to plain JSP. JSP is more comparable to "Classic ASP". If you're looking for the Java counterpart of ASP.NET(-MVC), look at JSF instead. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) for example has [a `<p:tabView>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf) which I think is exactly what you're looking for.

In plain JSP, you'd need to bring in some JavaScript code to execute Ajax requests and manipulate the HTML DOM and some Servlet to return the necessary data. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and maybe [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) may be helpful in this.

Comment: PrimeFaces is really nice BalusC. I will give it a try. Thank you very much. But I still want a code that doesn't uses third party library. Anyone please help...

Comment: Well, just write JavaScript/Ajax and Servlet code accordingly. You're familiar with it, I assume? If not, I'd start learning it. MDN has a really nice JS/Ajax tutorial. It's after all only going to take you weeks if not months   instead of a few hours or even less to finish it with the same degree of robustness and crossbrowser compatibility. You can always post a question here if you stucks with a specific coding problem.

Comment: thanks BalusC but I don't have enough time to learn a new thing. I have to submit my project soon. And thanks a lot for your help :) I will try to use PrimeFaces first

Answer (score 0):

With out your codes we are helpless..

Try the following code which changes the content image of a div to some other images on mouse over other divs. With some modifications it may reach up to your requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title><br />

</head>

<body>
<p>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeImage(img){
   document.getElementById('bigImage').src=img;

}
</script>

  <img src="../Pictures/lightcircle.png" alt="" width="284" height="156" id="bigImage" />
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<div>
  <p>
  <img src="../Pictures/lightcircle2.png" height=79 width=78 onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle2.png')"/>

 </p>
 <p><img src="../Pictures/lightcircle.png" alt="" width="120" height="100" onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle.png')"/></p>

 <p><img src="../Pictures/lightcircle2.png" alt="" width="78" height="79" onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle2.png')"/></p>

 <p>&nbsp;</p>


  </br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428063/1041341)